# javascript audio api play blob url

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, blob, web-audio-api

I worked out a testing function for `Web Audio API` to play url blob:

```js
// trigger takes a sound play function
function loadSound(url, trigger) {
    let context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // Decode asynchronously
    request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
        trigger(()=>{
            // play sound
            var source = context.createBufferSource(); // creates a sound source
            source.buffer = buffer;                    // tell the source which sound to play
            source.connect(context.destination);       // connect the source to the context's destination (the speakers)
            source.start();
        });
    }, e=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
    }
    request.send();
}



loadSound(url, fc=>{
    window.addEventListener('click', fc);
});
```

this is just for test, actually, I need a function to call to directly play the sound from url, if any current playing, quit it.

```js
let ac;
function playSound(url) {
    if(ac){ac.suspend()}
    let context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // Decode asynchronously
    request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
        // play sound
        let source = context.createBufferSource();  // creates a sound source
        source.buffer = buffer; // tell the source which sound to play
        source.connect(context.destination);    // connect the source to the context's destination (the speakers)
        // source.noteOn(0);    // play the source now
        ac = context;
        source.start();
    }, e=>{
        console.log(e);
    });
    }
    request.send();
}


window.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    playSound(url);
});
```

I did not do much modification, however, the second version, triggers works fine, but always produces no sound.

I suspect it may be `this` variable scope issue, I will be very glad if you can help me debug it.

since the blob url is too long, I put two versions in code pen.

1. [working version](https://codepen.io/MessizQin/pen/oNdNRKg)
2. [not working version](https://codepen.io/MessizQin/pen/mdLdYNr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `supsend` on the stored `AudioContext`, save a reference to the `AudioBufferSourceNode` that is currently playing. Then check if the reference exits and call `stop()` whenever you play a new sound.

```
const context = new AudioContext();
let bufferSource = null;

function playSound(url) {
  if (bufferSource !== null) {
    bufferSource.stop();
    bufferSource = null;
  }

  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, (buffer) => {
      bufferSource = context.createBufferSource();
      bufferSource.buffer = buffer; 
      bufferSource.connect(context.destination); 
      bufferSource.start();
      bufferSource.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        bufferSource = null;
      });
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
  request.send();
}


window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  playSound(url);
});
```